# Import list of dicts or JSON file to elastic search with python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have a `.json.gz` file that I wish to load into elastic search.

My first attempt involved using the `json` module to convert the JSON to a list of dicts.

```
import gzip
import json
from pprint import pprint
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

nodes_f = gzip.open("nodes.json.gz")
nodes = json.load(nodes_f)
```

Dict example:

```
pprint(nodes[0])

{u'index': 1,
 u'point': [508163.122, 195316.627],
 u'tax': u'fehwj39099'}
```

Using Elasticsearch:

```
es = Elasticsearch()

data = es.bulk(index="index",body=nodes)
```

However, this returns:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u'Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]')
```

Beyond this, I wish to be able to find the `tax` for given `point` query, in case this has an impact on how I should be indexing the data with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alfe pointed me in the right direction, but I couldn't get his code to work.

I found two solutions:

Line by line with a for loop:

```
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

for node in nodes:
    _id = node['index']
    es.index(index='nodes',doc_type='external',id=_id,body=node)
```

In bulk, using `helper`:

```
actions = [
    {
    "_index" : "nodes_bulk",
    "_type" : "external",
    "_id" : str(node['index']),
    "_source" : node
    }
for node in nodes
]

helpers.bulk(es,actions)
```

Bulk was around `22` times faster for a list of `343724` dicts.

Comment: why is there an underscore before index, type, id and source?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my working code using bulk api:

Define a list of dicts:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

doc = [{'_id': 1,'price': 10, 'productID' : 'XHDK-A-1293-#fJ3'},
   {'_id':2, "price" : 20, "productID" : "KDKE-B-9947-#kL5"}, 
   {'_id':3, "price" : 30, "productID" : "JODL-X-1937-#pV7"},
   {'_id':4, "price" : 30, "productID" : "QQPX-R-3956-#aD8"}]

helpers.bulk(es, doc, index='products',doc_type='_doc', request_timeout=200)
```

Comment: why they are removing doc_type in future releases!!, type is nothing but table

Answer (score 3):

The ES bulk library showed several problems, including performance trouble, not being able to set specific `_id`s etc.  But since the bulk API of ES is not very complicated, we did it ourselves:

```
import requests

headers = { 'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'text/plain'}

jsons = []
for d in docs:
   _id = d.pop('_id')  # take _id out of dict
   jsons.append('{"index":{"_id":"%s"}}\n%s\n' % (_id, json.dumps(d)))
data = ''.join(jsons)
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

We needed to set a specific `_id` but I guess you can skip this part in case you want a random `_id` set by ES automatically.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @alfie. Would you be able to annotate this? For example, I can't understand what `docs` is right now.

Comment: `docs` is a list of documents (dicts); your `nodes` seems to be the same structure.  `jsons` holds a list of json-encoded versions of these documents, each introduced by what the bulk-API of ES needs, small one-line-json dicts containing the bulk-task ("index this!") and additional information, e. g. with what `_id` this document is supposed to be indexed.

Comment: Ok. And why are you using `requests`? As I said, the data in question is being read from a document and there is no need to request via a `url`

Comment: The `requests` module is just one way to transport your data to ES for it to index it.  It replaces the `es.bulk()` call from your code.